# validate hyperlink and checkbox before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

For eaxmple in case the checkbox is not checked and the user hits the submit we need to show the error message "please check the checkbox". in case if the checkbox is checked and the hyper link is not clicked by the user we need to show the error message "Please click the link".
My Code

```
             <script>
             var state = 0;
             $("#AcceptMe").click(function()
              {
              state=1;
             });
             if(state == 0)
              {
              alert("please click");
              }
              </script>
              </head>
               <body>
               <form>
               <a id="Link1" href="#">click</a>
               <input type="checkbox" id="AcceptMe">
               <input type="submit" name="submit">
               </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good solution, because when the user clicks twice, he/she unchecks the checkbox, but the "state" would still be 1.

Check if the checkbox is checked like this:

```
var isChecked = $('#AcceptMe').is(':checked')?true:false;
```

Now the "isChecked" variable will contain true or false so you should first give the submit button an ID and type="button" (otherwise it will try to submit):

```
<input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" id="submitForm"/>
```

Add a clickHandler for the link like this:

```
var linkClicked = false;
$('#Link1').click(function(){
    linkClicked = true;
});
```

Then under that function your javascript add a clickhandler to the submitbutton:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $('#AcceptMe').attr('checked')?true:false;
    if(isChecked){
        alert('checked!');
        if(linkClicked){
            alert('Link clicked!');
        }
        else{
            alert('Click link first!');
        }
    else{
        alert('please check the checkbox!');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8o4an9xf/

Please note that you should add target="_blank", because the link will otherwise override the document.location. Or you could open the content you want to show in a modal window (which is nicer).

Comment: Check my edit, when someone clicks the link, the page will refresh. So you should make the link open in a new window OR open it in some modal window.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. But if i click submit nthng gets happng

Comment: I've edited my answer and create a JSfiddle right here: http://jsfiddle.net/8o4an9xf/

Comment: s i tried the same code what you suggestd but i dont knw y when i click submit button nthng gets happng

Comment: i tried both HTML and JS in same page as well as in seperate pages

Comment: My JSfiddle works, right? If you copy / paste that, it should work. Are you including JQuery correct?

Comment: ya am including JQuery correct.. but still its nt cumng

Comment: if your code is exactly the same as mine, it should work. But I can't help you if you keep saying it doesn't work. Could you provide a JSfiddle?

Comment: You didn't include JQuery, clear error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You might want to read into javascript first, because renaming $ to jquery doesn't include jquery. You have to download the JQuery javascript file and include it in the <head> of your html file. JQuery is an optional library, so you can't just use it. In my fiddle, in the top left corner, I included it under Frameworks and Extensions. Read here about how to include JQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: No problem! Please check this as the right answer, so people know that this helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use "return false"

My code is clear and simple.
If its not matter for you to have in-line code try below:

```
    <body>
    <form>
        <a id="Link1" href="#" onclick="$('#Link1').addClass('visited');
            alert('add \'visited\' class to \'#Link1\'');">
        </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="AcceptMe" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="
            if(  $('#AcceptMe').is(':checked')){                    
                alert('checkbox is :'  + $('#AcceptMe').is(':checked'));
                if(!$('#Link1').hasClass('visited')){
                    alert('please visit link1');
                    return false;
                };   
            }else{
            return false;
            }
        " />
    </form>
</body>
```